# VBA Get html element valure

Tags: html, excel, vba, class, screen-scraping

I need to retrieve the cost of some product from a site, in the image you can see the html code realtive to the pric. How do i get the 16.45 value with VBA from this HTML CODE (image)?

https://www.lca-distribution.com/eleaf/915-istick-pico-75w-tc-single-eleaf.html

[image]

```
    '<div class="box-info-product">
     '<div class="content_prices clearfix">
     '<div>
       '<p class="our_price_display"
       'itemprop="offers" itemscope=""
       'itemtype="https://schema.org/Offer">
       '<link itemprop="availability" href="https://schema.org/InStock">
       '<span id="our_price_display"
       'class="price" itemprop="price"
       'content="16.4496">16,45 €</span> HT
       '<meta itemprop="priceCurrency"
       'content="EUR">
    '</p>
```

My code:

```
  Sub BC_LEECH_S(ipath)
  Dim ie As Object
  Dim trgt_rng As Range
  Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim td As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim tr As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim trObj As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement
    Dim tdObj As MSHTML.HTMLGenericElement
    Dim Input_date_begin As Date
  Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    ie.Visible = False

    ie.navigate ipath

        Do
        DoEvents
        Loop Until ie.READYSTATE = 4
ie.Visible = True

Set e = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("our_price_display")

...
```

Comment: `ie.document.getElementById("our_price_display").innerText` as it is an id value not class.

Comment: Returns the error 424 Object Required

Comment: you either need a longer wait or the element is inside a frame/iframe. Don't use SET if using the line I gave.

Comment: Returns the same error also without the set, probabily it's inside another frame, i've modified the post with more code of the html page.

Comment: Did you try executing code line by line with f8 to allow more time?

Comment: yes, i've put the stop code (red point on the left of the line), waited, and then pressed F8

Comment: ok... then check for a parent iframe/frame

Comment: What you mean for parenti iframe?